# How to use Unified FFI in Pharo for integer buffer

Tags: pharo

There is very little documentation on how to use Unified FFI in Pharo. I would like to know how to deal with the following situation...

Let's say you have a shared C library (called testlib.so) with the following function signature:

```
void func1(int *buf);
```

How would you use uFFI to call this function? How would you complete the following code fragment:

```
self ffiCall: #( void func1(??? buf) ) module: 'testlib.so'.
```

where buf should hold whatever integer value func1 puts into it. Maybe buf needs to be prepared somehow before the ffiCall?

Comment: Should not buf be an Array? I think the preparation should be creating an array of integers, that go as parameter for the function

Answer (score 3):

It all goes through ByteArray for this kind of stuff.

So, something like:

```
SomeLib>>func1: aBuf
self ffiCall: #( void func1(ByteArray * aBuf) ) module: 'testlib.so'.

"int being 4 bytes, and signed"

inoutBuf := ByteArray new: 4.
inoutBuf integerAt: 1 put: 42 size: 4 signed: true.

SomeLib uniqueInstance func1: inoutBuf.

out := inoutBuf at: 1 size: 4 signed: true.
```

HTH